# calcular diferencia entre fechas

Tags: php, date

Estoy tratando de calcular la diferencia entre dos fechas con formato `Y-m-d H:i:s`por ejemplo `2017-04-10 22:39:09` par que me muestre la diferencia de días, horas y minutos. Una de las fechas será la que esté en la BDD y la otra la actual lo que tengo por el momento es esto:

```
//Hago la consulta etc... y esta es la variable donde almacenaré la fecha
$fec_ = transcurridoPublicacion($fila['Prod_Fec']);
```

La función que lo calcula:

```
function transcurridoPublicacion($fecha){
    $fecha2 = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    $fechaF = date_diff($fecha, $fecha2);
    return $fechaF;          
}
```

Comment: ¿Y donde estas teniendo problemas?

Comment: Me devuelve: Warning: :  date_diff() expects parameter 1 to be DateTimeInterface, string given in ....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

puedes calcularlo de la siguiente manera:

```
function transcurridoPublicacion($fecha){
    $fecha1 = date($fecha);
    $fecha2 = new DateTime('2011-01-03 17:13:00');
    $fechaF = $fecha->diff($fecha2);
// Lo siguiente es por si quieres ponerlo ya en texto la diferencia
//  $elapsed = $interval->format('%y años %m meses %a dias %h horas %i minutos %S segundos');
//  return $elapsed;
    return $fechaF;          
}
```

Comment: Buena respuesta. Aunque yo haría el código coherente creando `$fecha1` como se crea `$fecha2`. La mezcla de estilos no es recomendable, no sólo por estética, sino también por comprensión del código para futuros usuarios / colaboradores en un proyecto... **`$fecha1 = new DateTime($fecha);`**

Answer (score 3):

Puedes intentar algo como esto:

```
$fechaF = $fecha->diff($fecha2);
```

Igual [aquí](http://php.net/manual/es/datetime.diff.php) te dejo la documentación.

Y lo imprimes:

```
print $fechaF->format("%H:%I:%S");
```