# Calcular diferencia de horas php

Tags: php

Tengo una aplicación web en la que los usuarios pueden insertar las horas extras que han realizado. Un problema que tengo es que hice una función en la que me calcula la diferencia de horas. En la aplicación, si un usuario ha trabajado menos o 4 horas, esas horas se les pagan, en cambio si ha trabajado más 4 horas, el usuario tiene la posibilidad de elegir si quiere que se le pague o convertirlas en un día de vacaciones. El problema de la función es por ejemplo:

Si usuario1 trabajó el sábado desde las 8:00 hasta las 12:10, la función debería dejarme poder elegir pero no me deja ya que aunque ponga hasta las 12:59 me lo cuenta como 4 horas en vez de 4:59 horas.

Aquí mi función:

```
$datetime1 = new DateTime({FECHA_INICIO});
$datetime2 = new DateTime({FECHA_FIN});
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
return $interval->format('%H:%I:%S');
```

Comment: Posible duplicado de [calcular diferencia entre fechas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/62122/calcular-diferencia-entre-fechas)

Comment: @Xerox te sugiero revisar en el sitio, en ocasiones la información que necesitas ya se encuentra; https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/62122/calcular-diferencia-entre-fechas saludos!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Te comento lo siguiente, deberías tener tu código de la siguiente manera

```
<?php

$apertura = new DateTime('08:00:00');
$cierre = new DateTime('12:59:00');

$tiempo = $apertura->diff($cierre);

echo $tiempo->format('%H horas %i minutos');
//retornará 4:59
```

> Fijate en el formato que lo coloque para el caso de las horas va en
>   hrs:minutos:segundos entre comillas

Por lo demás tu código esta bien

Ahora si colocara los valores de inicio y fin como constantes, el uso de las llaves que tu pusiste estaría de mas, aquí te dejo un ejemplo

```
<?php
DEFINE('HORA_INICIO', '08:00:00');
DEFINE('HORA_FIN', '12:59:00');
$apertura = new DateTime(HORA_INICIO);
$cierre = new DateTime(HORA_FIN);

$tiempo = $apertura->diff($cierre);

echo $tiempo->format('%H:%I');
```

Fuente de referencia

http://php.net/manual/es/datetime.diff.php