# Problema al restar Fechas PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy haciendo un código para restar fechas, pero al ejecutarlo me sale un mensaje que no puedo corregir, les dejo el código y el mensaje.

Me gustaria me ayudaran a ver como puedo corregirlo

```html
<?php
require("../conexion.php");
 
$consulta = "SELECT * FROM tpersonal WHERE TPER_IDPER='2525'";
 
$resultado = $mysqli->query($consulta); 
$row = $resultado->fetch_array();



$fecha_inicio = date('Y/m/d');
$fecha_fin = date ('Y/m/d', strtotime($row['TPER_FECHA']));
$total = date($fecha_fin) - date ($fecha_inicio);
echo "<p> Fecha de hoy: $fecha_inicio </a> </p>";
echo "<p> Fecha que vence: $fecha_fin </a> </p>";
echo "<p> Total: $total </a> </p>";



?>
```

[image: Error al ejecutar código]

Comment: No puedes usar `-` para restar fechas.  Necesitas usar `date_diff()`.

Comment: @Sr1871 realmente es duplicada de otra pregunta, donde [la respuesta aceptada es esta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/62125/29967). Muestra la mejor forma no sólo de restar las fechas, sino de construir el objeto a partir del resultado. Por cierto Erik, no uses formatos cuando crees objetos fecha. Los formatos son para la salida (presentación en pantalla), no para la creación de objetos.

Comment: muchísimas gracias, ya pude resolver el problema, realmente este código solo era un ejemplo, ya que en el sistema se manejara un limite para que la contraseña expire y manejaba un contador de tiempo.